# Attribute layout ScrollFlag Not found

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am not able use

```
app:layout_scrollFlag="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
```

Whenever I am using it, I get an error:

> AAPT: error: attribute layout_scrollFlag (aka com.shashank.myapplication.spyder.ncrb_first:layout_scrollFlag) not found.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#FCFCFC">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:background="@drawable/u_shape"
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlag="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:title="Sanrakshan"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/u_shape"
        >
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarID"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed `"s"`:

```
app:layout_scrollFlag="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
```

**Use:**

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```